# Is there any way of mentioning two login_redirect_urls in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my application, if the user logs in for the first time, he is redirected to the profile page and from the second time, he is redirected to the homepage (VChome in my appliation).
So I decided to write this in urls.py and views.py

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('VC/',views.VChome, name='VChome'),
    path('profile/',views.update_profile,name='profile'),
    path('users/login/', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('login/done/', LoginRedirectView.as_view(), name='login_redirect'),       
]
```

views.py

```
class LoginRedirectView(generic.View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        userLL = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        # print(userLL)
        last_login = userLL.last_login
        # print(last_login)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                if last_login == None:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("profile"))
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("VChome"))
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
        <strong><p>Sign in</p></strong>
        <p>Username</p>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"  placeholder="Username">
        <p>Password</p>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">      
  </form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I have templates profile.html and VChome.html and I'm sure that they are rendered correctly in views.py

The problem here is if I mention LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'VChome', the login page is redirected to VChome.

If I don't mention it, login page is redirected to /accounts/profile

I want the login page to be redirected based on the last_login constraint mentioned in login_user in views.py

Comment: This should be working as you want as far as I can tell. Is there a GET querystring param being sent called `next` when you hit the login page?

Comment: @schillingt Nope. I didn't use any GET in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep it simple, and create a view that would do the logic and return a redirect to either `VChome` or wherever else.

`views.py`

```py
class LoginRedirectView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.blahblah:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('CAhome'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
```

`urls.py`

```py
    ...
    path('login/done/', LoginRedirectView.as_view(), name='login_redirect'),
    ...
```

`settings.py`

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login_redirect'
```

---

Technically, you could call a different view from the same request, thus saving the user one HTTP redirect. But I think it is probably not worth the effort for this particular use case...